# SQLite - Insert Command is taking 10s on 1200 records

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, insert

```
using (SQLiteTransaction trans = sql_con.BeginTransaction())
{
    commandInsert.Transaction = trans;

    commandInsert.Parameters["@One"].Value = "ONE";
    commandInsert.Parameters["@Two"].Value = "TWO";
    commandInsert.Parameters["@Three"].Value = "THREE";
    commandInsert.Parameters["@Four"].Value = "FOUR";
    commandInsert.Parameters["@FIVE"].Value = "FIVE";
    commandInsert.Parameters["@SIX"].Value = "SIX";
    commandInsert.Parameters["@SEVEN"].Value = "SEVEN";
    commandInsert.Parameters["@EIGHT"].Value = "EIGHT";
    commandInsert.Parameters["@NINE"].Value = "NINE";
    commandInsert.Parameters["@TEN"].Value = "TEN";
    commandInsert.Parameters["@ELEVEN"].Value = "ELEVEN";
    commandInsert.Parameters["@CommentCount"].Value = 
    commandInsert.Parameters["@NUMBER1"].Value = 5;
    commandInsert.Parameters["@NUMBER2"].Value = 6;
    commandInsert.Parameters["@NUMBER3"].Value = 8;

    commandInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();

    trans.Commit();
}
```

I'm using parametrized command on transacion to insert 1300 records.
I have one index on one uniq column, but even when i remove index this is still taking 10s.

This is my connection string:

```
string ConnectionString = 
      "Data Source=Data/database.db3;Version=3;Compress=True;Count Changes=off;Journal Mode=off;Pooling=true;" + 
      "Cache Size=10000;Page Size=4096;Synchronous=off";
```

How i can speed up this?

**EDIT**
Problem solved...
The problem was in detecting language not in inserting (which is taking 3ms).
Sorry for taken time...

Comment: Looking at your code snippet, it looks like you're starting a transaction for *each* insert rather than having a single transaction for all 1300 records.  Have you tried doing that?

Comment: The code is incomplete/not you actual code. Please post your real code or a complete example, that produces your results. With this (not compilable) snipped, we do not see where and how you are looping the records.

Comment: How much indexes have you put on your table?

Answer (score -2):

If you are using SQL server, you can use the "Display Estimated Execution plan" on your SQL statement to find if there is one part that is taking more resources than another. For example if you using the results of a select query to populate a table, the select with complicated joins may be slowing this down.

Comment: My point is that you can port the command into sql server to try, SQLite has no decent profiling

Comment: Which will tell him how SQL Server will execute it, not SQLite.

Comment: @StevenWood SQLite has [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html). Anyway, the execution plan is not helpful for a simple insert statement.